# cfdirectory on a ColdFusion Mapping

Tags: coldfusion, mapping, cfdirectory

I am trying to use CFDirectory to get a file listing of a mapping created in ColdFusion Admin. So far I cannot get the list to populate, but if I reference the physical path the full file list is displayed.

Here's the code I'm using:

`<cfoutput>
<cfdirectory action="list" directory="mymapping" name="test"><cfdump var="#test#">
</cfoutput>`

Thanks,

Jon C.

Comment: The mapping is setup in CF Admin "Logical Path" is /mymapping and "Physical Path" is D:\home\mydomain.com\wwwroot\mystuff

Neither one of the suggestions thus far have worked, the first does not apply because this is not a path set in a variable.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how the mapping is set up - you may need to give it the full "virtual" path:

```
<cfdirectory action="list" directory="/mapping/folder" name="test">
<cfdump var="#test#">
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the form `/mymapping`, with the `/` in front. And you need to use `ExpandPath` to expand the “virtual” directory as defined in the mapping `/mymapping`. That way, you end up using `cfdirectory` and passing in a physical directory, one that actually exists on the hard drive and not just in the ColdFusion mappings.

```
<cfdirectory
    name = "theQuery"
    action = "list"
    directory = "#ExpandPath("/mymapping")#"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting the directory in a variable called "mymapping".  It would be as follows:

```
<cfdirectory action="list" directory="#mymapping#" name="test">
<cfdump var="#test#">
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say which version of CF are you using, so Goyix's solution is partially correct: it works with the Railo, but not ACF.

In ACF8+ you can use the ServiceFactory to extract the real path. Code can look like this:

```
<cfset mapping = "/fusebox5" />

<cfset serviceFactory = createObject("java","coldfusion.server.ServiceFactory") />
<cfset mappings = serviceFactory.runtimeService.getMappings() />

<cfif StructKeyExists(mappings, mapping)>
    <cfdirectory action="list" directory="#mappings[mapping]#" name="test">
    <cfdump var="#test#">
<cfelse>
    <p>Mapping not found</p>
</cfif>
```

Note: used my existing FB5 mapping for the testing.

**EDIT**

Proposed later method with ExpandPath is much clearer. Leaving this one only as possibly useful alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (not tested):

```
<cfset expandedPath=getDirectoryFromPath(expandPath("/mymapping/*.*")) />
<cfdirectory action="list" directory="#expandedPath#" name="dirListing" />
<cfdump var="#dirListing#" />
```